# WIX installer asks to close third party applications while uninstalling application

Tags: wix

I am using WIX Installer for my WPF application, when the application is uninstalled or upgraded to newer version,it asks to close some third party applications such as Microsoft Outlook,Notepad++,etc. I am unable to find the solution for this. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should do more research before asking a new question on SO. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31801340/6868669) can be an answer to your question.